# Opamp driving 24V signal through long wire

Tags: operational-amplifier, wire

I have an opamp working as comparator that creates a 24V pulse signal (appx. 400ms duration) that needs to go through a wire of 10-20m length. Is a normal opamp capable of driving this or is there a certain common circuit to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, but we know quite little what's the actual problem. Any voltage propagates in a cable a long way, but can get spoiled. "Working as comparator " suggests it's not a signal which must keep its amplitude exactly. Created with an opamp and 400ms pulse length suggess there's no need to keep certain rise and fall time. I guess you do not want any ringing. But what's the load, can you restore the pulse in the receiving end and what's the shortest gap between 2 pulses which must stay recognizable? Is there serious noise sources  or potential differences between the receiver and the transmitter?

Comment: can you tell us a little about your *pulse*? Is it just a voltage rectangle? 400ms is about eternity for electronics, how fast do your edges need to be? Which edges are important to your application? If only the rising (or falling), why not simply use a MOSFET with a pull-down (or pull-up) resistor instead of your opamp? If you want fast rising AND falling edge, a MOSFET pair and a gate driver for that pair would make this easy.

Comment: Sequential pulses are not a problem, if one is recognized that's enough. The sampling rate on the other end of the wire is somewhere in the range of 10Hz, that's the reason for the pulse duration. RIse and fall time is uncritical in my opinion, I was just not sure if an ordinary omamp has enough driving capability. A MOSFET probably is a good idea, didn't consider this.

Comment: MC1488  is the common RS232 line driver - capable of making 24V peak-to-peak signals, (but usually used as +12V  to -12V)

Comment: What are you driving with this pulse? If it's a high impedance load the answer is yes (for an opamp that can output 24V). If it's a relay, solenoid, big lamp or motor, probably no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most op-amps will effectively drive a capacitive load providing there's a series output resistor used. Given also that your application doesn't involve negative feedback (you are operating as a comparator) there should be realistically no problems of instability leading to oscillations to worry about.

Depending on the op-amp and the type of load at the end of the cable and what sort of attenuation you can tolerate, I'd use a 220 ohm resistor in series with the op-amp output. It would help if the op-amp is known though.

> *It's a 24V digital input of a controller so I'd assume there's not
>   much load. I just have no experience with these kind of signal
>   transmition*

OK a couple of things you need to be aware of here: -

- if the op-amp power supply is 24 volts then the maximum op-amp output (without a more specialist choice) will be about 22 volts for a regular non-rail-to-rail device
- Assuming above, the minimum output might only be 2 volts above ground
- You need to decide whether this is acceptable and if not either choose slightly different power rails for the op-amp or choose a rail-to-rail device
- I'd also be tempted to put a unidirectional TVS diode across the output that feeds the cable (output to local 0 volts)
- You also want to avoid ground loops so if your op-amp power supply is grounded and the digital controller 0 volts is also grounded, you might need to take precautions to avoid ground loops circulating any ground fault currents from machines locally through the interconnecting cable. This might mean opto-isolating the op-amp output.

Comment: The opamp type is not yet defined actually

Comment: What about the load at the end of the cable?

Comment: It's a 24V digital input of a controller so I'd assume there's not much load. I just have no experience with these kind of signal transmition

Comment: I think ground loops should not be a problem, the opamp is fed by the same power supply as the controller and does not have any direct ground. But thanks for the hint with the opto isolation and the TVS, that might be a good idea!

Answer (score 1):

They are called cable driver, buffer. For example THS3201 but this may not suit your demand for such voltage, also it is very fast and expensive. You may search for an opamp that can drive capacitive load, has high slew rate,...for example OPA192,

Read this article: https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/ask-the-applications-engineer-25.html